# Finding the index of the first row in a Pandas DataFrame, starting from a specific index and moving backwards, until condition is met

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame and I'm trying to find the index of the first row where two column values differ. However, I need to start searching in reverse order.

Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Column1': [1, 2, 3, 5, 5],
        'Column2': [1, 1, 3, 5, 5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Here, for example, I want to start from the second last index until I find the first index, where the column values differ. Thus, the desired Output would be "1".

Comment: Would 'np.where' help in this situation? Something like this: ```df['result']=np.where(df['Column1] == df["Column2], True, False)``` help? Then, you can filter by the bool value resulted or navigate to your desired index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter rows by indexing, e.g. to `i` value of index, comapre for not equal by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) and last use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.last_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.last_valid_index.html):

*Notice: If no difference output is `None`.*

```
i = 3
s = df.loc[:i, 'Column1'].ne(df.loc[:i, 'Column2'])  

out = s[s].last_valid_index()
```

Another idea with `next` and `iter`:

```
i = 3
s = df.loc[:i, 'Column1'].ne(df.loc[:i, 'Column2'])  

out = next(iter(s.index[s][::-1]), None)
```

Comment: why do you actually do `out = s[s].last_valid_index()` and not `out = s.last_valid_index()`

Comment: @kklaw - If omit filtering by mask get last value `False` instead last value `True` of Series `s`

Comment: But don't you need to apply the mask to the dataframe instead of the mask itself?

Comment: @kklaw - No, it is not necessary, because finally need `index`, so `s[s].last_valid_index` or `df[s].last_valid_index` working same

Comment: I undestand. Wouldn't also `s.idxmax()`work? If no difference occurs, it would not return `None`, but otherwise they should be equal. What would be more time efficient?

Comment: @kklaw - Yes, but there is one issue. If all values are same like `data = {'Column1': [1, 2, 3, 5, 5],
        'Column2': [1, 2, 3, 5, 5]}` it return first value, not `None` like `last_valid_index`. Depends of data, if never same columns values is possible use `idxmax`